# Creating a Total Count Using Dropdown Menus in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm designing an attendance sheet and need to total the selections from a dropdown menu for each student.

The drop down options are:

> Present
> Late
> Unexcused
> Absence
> Excused
> Absence

I have a total cell assigned to each student for each option, but I need to formulate a way to calculate these totals.

Comment: It will much easier for everyone that you provide a sample of a sheet with dummy data which represent you have tried to do and what is expected, you will get a quicker response

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `=COUNTIFS()` function to calculate the total number of instances per attendance status. For example:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A, "Student A", B2:B, "Present")
```

See sample screenshots below:

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4LnX.png)

[Typing the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVEGI.gif)